# how to send SOAP request with SSL certificate in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to send a SOAP - PHP request with a DER certificate (that means the certificate don't have a privateKey) but no success.

```
$local_cert = FULL_PATH_TO_MY_CERT;

   $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                'local_cert' => $local_cert,
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
                'compression' => (SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP),
                'location' => 'https://webserviceurl:port/ws/servlet/ws'
            ));
```

Only I recieve this errors:

Warning (2): SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: Unable to set private key file `PATHTOMYLOCALCERT' [APP\Vendor\WebServices\MyWS.php, line 206]

Warning (2): SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to create an SSL handle [APP\Vendor\WebServices\MyWS.php, line 206]

Warning (2): SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: Failed to enable crypto [APP\Vendor\WebServices\MyWS.php, line 206]

Warning (2): SoapClient::SoapClient(https://webserviceurl:port/ws/servlet/ws?wsdl) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: operation failed [APP\Vendor\WebServices\MyWS.php, line 206]

Warning (2): SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://webserviceurl:port/ws/servlet/ws?wsdl" [APP\Vendor\WebServices\MyWS.php, line 206]

but I've found a little trick (in php.net) using the function file_get_contents($local_cert); the errors are gone.

But a new error come from.

Result : string(773) "Error reading prefix:Action.Execute"

What I mean is... this error above... is comming from the WebService? because it cannot authenticate with my request?

Thanks everybody. (appreciate your answers)

Comment: something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187646/soapclient-not-sending-certificate

Answer (score 7):

I'm using SSL certificate in my soap call.

In My case I'm giving absolute path on my server for `wsdl` and for `local_cert`
I've already defined those in my class. Please note that I'm using my certificate in `.pem` format.

```
public $local_cert = "/var/www/.../webroot/cert.pem";
public $wsdl = "/var/www/.../webroot/my_wsdl.wsdl";

$this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array(
        "trace"         => 1, 
        "exceptions"    => true, 
        "local_cert"    => $this->local_cert, 
        "uri"           => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",
        "style"         => SOAP_RPC,
        "use"           => SOAP_ENCODED,
        "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_2 ,
        "location"      => $this->location
    )
);
```

In my certificate there are 2 parts. Certificate and RSA Private Key.

```
(1)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFjzCC....
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
(2)-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAI....
....
ww==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----
```

And most important you should use `https` link for making a soap call. This is working fine for me.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: **"uri" => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes"**
This is really necessary?? I can't connect yet.