# SOAP Client over HTTPS with SSL certificates on both sides

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ssl, soap-client

I have to develop a SOAP Client, and the supplier send me this specifications:

- *Will be transmited using HTTPS through IP, and will be Packaged as XML documents that adjust to the diferent defnitions of XML scheme.*
- *The Communications is synchronous, the third party should wait for response.*
- *Each request and response will be signed.*

I'm using the soapClient class from PHP, and all works fine, except when I try to use my private key to establish communication with the server:

```
Code: WSDL | Message: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://remoteserver/CustomerManagementService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://remoteserver/CustomerManagementService?wsdl
```

Then I tried creating a .pem file, it contains my private key concatenated with my certificate, as I've read in: [how to send SOAP request with SSL certificate in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676392/how-to-send-soap-request-with-ssl-certificate-in-php)

But it still returns an error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://remoteserver:80/CustomerManager/proxy/CustomerManagementService?WSDL%2FGWTCommonResources%2Fwsdl%2FGWTCommonMessages' : failed to load external entity "http://remoteserver:80/CustomerManager/proxy/CustomerManagementService?WSDL%2FGWTCommonResources%2Fwsdl%2FGWTCommonMessages
```

I wonder if there is some way to get exactly the raw data that is being sent by the soapClient class of PHP. And where I must set the certificate of the supplier.

I've already tried with "$client->__getLastRequest()", but I'm getting a NULL. This is my code:

```
$client = new anotherSoapClient($service, array(
    'local_cert'    => $pem, 
    'style'         => SOAP_RPC,
    'use'           => SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2,
    'authentication'=> SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
    'ssl'           => array(
        'ciphers'=> "SHA1",
        'verify_peer' => false, 
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ),
    'https' => array(
        'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false,
        'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => false
    ),
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'cache_ttl'     => 86400,
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
));

// Test connection
echo BR.'Functions: <pre>';var_dump($client->__getFunctions());echo '</pre>';

$XMLrequest = $client->prepareRequest($email);
$response = $client->__anotherRequest('getCustomerInfo', $XMLrequest);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

By the way, I'm using PHP 5.4.9 on my local machine and the server have PHP 5.3.10 and anotherSoapClient is a class who extend PHP soapClient class: [PHP soapClient send custom XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009554/php-soapclient-send-custom-xml)

Answer (score 2):

For debugging proposals your SOAP request you have to extend the SoapClient class.

```
class SoapClientDebug extends SoapClient
    {
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
        {
            // Add code to inspect/dissect/debug/adjust the XML given in $request here

            // Uncomment the following line, if you actually want to do the request
            // return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
      }
    }
```

And next use it in your request:

```
$client = new SoapClientDebug("x.wsdl");
        $response = $client->__soapCall($function);
        echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

Hope it helps to debug your code!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify following SoalClient options:

```
$defaultEndpoint = "https://remoteserver/CustomerManagementService";
$uri = "https://remoteserver";
$client = new anotherSoapClient($service, array(
    'local_cert'    => $pem, 
    'location'      => $defaultEndpoint,
    'uri'           => $uri,   
    'style'         => SOAP_RPC,
    'use'           => SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2,
    'authentication'=> SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
    'ssl'           => array(
        'ciphers'=> "SHA1",
        'verify_peer' => false, 
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ),
    'https' => array(
        'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false,
        'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => false
    ),
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'cache_ttl'     => 86400,
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
));
```