# OpenSSL encryption is required in php to send data through network?

Tags: php, openssl

Do I have to use any further encryption method in php with openSSL to send data in network, even if openSSL certificate is installed on server, does it encrypt and decrypts data automatically before sending and recieving data?

Comment: If you are using apache you will need `mod_openssl` otherwise you will need to follow the instructions for whatever server software you are using. Using SSL does not mean your server is secure and you should still do a very careful check for XSS, SQL injection, CSRF, etc. or higher someone else to check for you before deploying

Comment: yah i m concerned about sql injection and all the problem is, i have encrypted password with many other functions, but i want to verify the  other data automatically gets encrypted or not while sending or recieving????????/

Comment: Well that in particular is a really easy fix. Just escape all your query strings that involve user input.

Comment: hmm i m not getting u,

Comment: i just want to know if openSSL certificate automatically encrypts data or not if installed on server?

Comment: I was referring to the first part of your comment. For your question could you post the your operating system and server software? And I am not quite sure what you mean by installing the certificates on the server. Did you just copy the files in or did you do all of the necessary configuration. If I knew what software you were using I could answer your question better or at least point you to the right documentation

Comment: its Ubuntu and apache2 server..

Comment: I think this may help: http://www.dannytsang.co.uk/index.php/create-and-enable-ssl-on-ubuntu-lamp-server/

Comment: are you a security reseacher?

Comment: "are you a security reseacher?" No not exactly I'm a teenaged  enthusiast. "anyways thanx 4 help" You're welcome!

Comment: oh yeah! i m a teen ager too..

Answer (score 0):

The question here is how you are sending the data? For example if you are sending SOAP you will need to send a local_cert parameter (see http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php or [SOAP Client over HTTPS with SSL certificates on both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295243/soap-client-over-https-with-ssl-certificates-on-both-sides)) So I think it will depend on how you're sending the data but once PHP knows what its doing it should translate the data for you automatically. With APACHE for example it certainly decodes the SSL encrypted traffic before it gets to PHP and that is done automatically.