# Invoke soapclient using SSL Certificate

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect a wsdl file using soapClient like

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://example.com/webservices?wsdl");
```

But my problem is ,The url is only accessible using its SSL certificate and key otherwise this url return error "SSL Certificate error".

Is it possible to connect the wsdl using SSL?

NOTE : It is not password protected ,I have no user name and password.Only one certificate pem file and its private key

Comment: @ RiggsFolly  I don't found anything from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php connect using certificate files

Comment: Well you can start by use `https://`

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually the url is https:// , http is by mistake

Comment: Do you have php_openssl activated in your php.ini

Comment: @RiggsFolly OpenSSL/1.0.1f is enabled

Comment: Does this give you some cluse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295243/soap-client-over-https-with-ssl-certificates-on-both-sides

Comment: Have you checked ALL the links in the sidebar called **Related**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130012/discussion-between-shijin-t-r-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the certificate to SoapClient

```
$wsdl = "https://my-server/?wsdl";
$my_cert_file = "/my/path/to/mycert.pem";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert', $my_cert_file) );
```